# Haskell: Using Network.Wreq to POST header with Content-Length: 0

Tags: haskell

I am consuming an API that has an endpoint of `/{id}/delete` that method type is POST, but requires an empty body, and so requires the header `Content-Length: 0` to be set.

I am using [Newtork.Wreq.Session.postWith](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.1.0/docs/Network-Wreq-Session.html#v:postWith) to send my request, but if I use an empty body, no body or content length header is included.

If I try to manually add the header using `& header "Content-Length" .~ ["0"]`, this is not included in the request.

Is there a way to get Wreq to add this header for an empty body?

Comment: When I post an empty ByteString, I _do_ see a Content-Length: 0. I'm using wreq-0.4.1.0 if that helps. https://gist.github.com/hlian/c403ed77d4011c749011bbb76e07d1a7

Comment: @haoformayor you are right. I can even see the header in fiddler. Its a problem with the service I am using, not with Wreq.